# Keeping a component in a fixed position within a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have a `JPanel` that uses a horizontal Box layout and contains a `JLabel` that I would like to keep in the exact same position as other components within the `JPanel` are `setVisible(false)`. Currently, the `JLabel` moves to the left as other components become invisible.

What's the easiest way to go about this?

**EDIT: Pics added**

So this is what the `JPanel` look like with all components visible

[image]

When I set the three `JTextFields` on the right to invisible, the `JLabel` set to text `X` moves to the left like this:

[image]

But I would like it to stay where it was like this:

[image]

**EDIT2**: I'm actually using Netbeans GUI editor's Free Design for this particular `JLabel`. I'm sorry for the mistake - I've been using a lot of BoxLayouts recently and I got confused!

Comment: Please, if you may, kindly provide a rough sketch of the expected view, that will really help us provide a genuine answer :-)

Comment: Yes that's a good idea. I've edited the post.

Comment: It's not user friendly to have GUI components appear and disappear.  It would be better to enable and disable the JTextFields.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I would agree normally but this is an eductional tool and making the JTextFields disappear is part of the functionality.

Comment: So it’s not about a “fixed” position but rather that the last “X” component should stay at the right edge? Just insert a [glue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createGlue--) right before the “X” component.

Comment: @Holger My mistake was forgetting that I was using a free design instead of a BoxLayout. Glue is clearly the solution here. Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Currently, the JLabel moves to the left as other components become invisible.

Yes, layout managers are designed to only work with visible components. I'm not sure if any of the default layout manager will work, but I would look into using the `GridBagLayout`, since this layout is based on a grid structure so as long as you have components in that grid on another row the label should not shift.

Otherwise, you could dislay the "other components" in a panel using a `CardLayout`. Then instead of making the components invisible, you swap the panel with an empty panel.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Edit:

Based on your picture the easiest solution is to use "glue":

```
panel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue);
panel.add(xLabel);
```

Now the label will always be displayed at the far right of the panel. Read the tutorial on [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more information about "glue".

Comment: See my Edit2. I'm really sorry for the mix up. It may be harder to answer my question now I've realised I'm using free design. I may just start again with a BoxLayout.

Comment: @notnek, it doesn't change my answer. Yes you should be using BoxLayout or other layout managers. "glue" is still the solution for BoxLayout.